# How does an application communicate with a webpage/server

Tags: java, webserver, html

I want for my java application which I have started to develop to 'communicate' with my webpage. However I have no experience with webpages and would like to know how things such as login using user/pass verification works. Any links to tutorials, where to start, and clarification would help me a lot! Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by your application *to 'communicate' with my webpage*? Please be more specific, note that this site is for developers to developers, not from end users to developers.

Comment: i think you basically want a web application with some login feature , right ?? its no separate application , simply learn to create a web application , start with learning servlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,You can use form at client side for send data to server side..

at at server side you can catch data by using getParameter method.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can communicate via AJAX
2. You can store data in session.setAttribute('name', name) / session.getAttribute('name')
3. You can pass some data in GET-parameters (request.getParameter('userID'))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop a simple web application with login functionality, you need to know following. You might want to start from 
[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebApp.html)

- Java
- Database (RDBMS or NOSQL)
- HTTP Servers/ Request / Response

If you have already developed web app providing some service (such as REST services), you can develop a web client using jquery/backbone.js.